# How can I redirect to step2 page after verify the email based on their role?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

How can I redirect to a step2 page after verifying the email based on their role?

[image]

Because I have two user types, both after register their email and pass, they will get a verification email, after that clicking button it redirects to home instead it will go to `/signup/employee/step2` or `/signup/user/step2`.

Can I ask some tips on how to redirect the user based on their role with their step2 to complete registration?

Answer (score 0):

Well, its obvious you'll need some type of ACL (access-control). If your app, need just that specific part, you can add a new column in your user table, `is_employee` and make it bool.

After that just implement a new middleware.

However, I would personally go with https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission it is way easier :)

Comment: I have ACL from https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission, only thing I don't know how to redirect based on their role after they click the button, cause it's different URL `http://recommendedresumes.test/email/verify/15?expires=1555245343&signature=9532e38215eb496b760347ed2a5756326f60982fe05a3758ead3ae7aeb4c0917`, this URL will redirect to home

Comment: That is just an overkill, you should have single source of truth, and verify users on the same way, no matter what their role is. That is just for the basic implementation, later on you can come up with your own logic. After, the verification has been completed, you can change the destination url to the let's say `/auth/selector`, and redirect based on that.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel exposes an Event when user verify his account, you can add a custom listener to it and redirect user where you want.

You need to do something like this:

```
// app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php
protected $listen = [
    'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Verified' => [ // Laravel event
        'App\Listeners\RedirectUsers', // Your custom listener
    ],
];
```

run `# php artisan make:listener RedirectUsers -e Illuminate\Auth\Events\Verified`

```
// app/Listeners/RedirectUsers.php
public function handle(OrderShipped $event)
{
     if(Auth::user()->hasRole('admin')) {
         return redirect('/admin');
     }
     // ...
}
```